# How to show a popup after 20 sec of an app open every time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer, popup

I need to show a popup every time when i open the app after 20 sec.

**code:** with this code i can show popup only when i open the app first time after 20 sec.. but **i need to show the same when i close the app and open again**.. how to do that? please guide me.

```
var timer = Timer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
} 

@objc func displayAlert()
{        
    print("after 20 sec")
    showPopup()
}
```

Comment: I think your timer is being deallocated after `viewDidLoad` scope ends

Comment: *"every time when i open the app after 20 sec"* -- Do you mean when your app **returns to the foreground** (e.g. when a user puts your app in the background / switches to a different app and comes back)? Or, do you mean only when your app **launches from a closed state**?

Comment: @DonMag, in this stage `only when your app launches from a closed state`

Comment: @ReinierMelian, i have edited post with my recent changes but still same.. please take a look

Comment: @SwiftiOS - *"only when your app launches from a closed state"* ... your code should be working as-is then. Maybe you're not sure what "a closed state" is? If you swipe up to "dismiss" your app -- so you now see the icons on you screen -- that does not ***close*** your app... it just moves it to the background. If you drag partially up - so you see the task switcher showing your "open" apps, and *then* swipe your app up and off the screen, **that** closes your app and your `viewDidLoad()` will run on the next launch.

Comment: @DonMag, oh yeah its my fault.. i mean to say when app returns in foreground then i need to show popup after 20 sec... like this `Do you mean when your app returns to the foreground (e.g. when a user puts your app in the background / switches to a different app and comes back)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to register for notification when your app becomes active...

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // all your normal stuff...
    
    // register to receive notification when App becomes active
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(startAlertTimer), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
@objc func startAlertTimer()
{
    print("start 20 sec timer")
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(showPopup), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
@objc func showPopup() {
    print("after 20 seconds, popup")
}
```

Comment: if i am in another viewcontroller then also after 10 sec popup coming, how to remove observer..i mean no need to call notification if i am in another view controller.. how? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

And if you use a DispatchQueue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) {
  // Do something here..
}
```